# How to proxy gRPC calls

Tags: proxy, grpc, charles-proxy, man-in-the-middle

I'm trying to analyse what information an app is sending so I setup Charles but to my surprise nothing was logged out.

After decompiling the app I see that it doesn't use simple REST calls but rather a library called gRPC.

Is there a good tool out there that will allow me too see what is send out from the app?

Comment: Hi, Looking for same. did you find any solution?

Comment: Any update @Vibhor ?

Comment: nope :(... still looking ..

Answer (score 3):

The [Mediator](https://github.com/ButterCam/Mediator) is a Cross-platform GUI gRPC debugging proxy like Charles but design for gRPC.

You can dump all gRPC requests without any configuration.

Mediator can render the binary message into a JSON tree, when you have the API schema.

It support decode gRPC/TLS, but you should download and install the Mediator Root Certificate to your device.

Comment: Hello, butter developer!

Answer (score 2):

gRPC uses HTTP/2 as a transport protocol. Any proxy which supports HTTP/2 for both the front-end and back-end connections should be able to be used to inspect the packets a gRPC connection. Note, some proxies only support HTTP/2 for the front-end or back-end connections and those are incompatible with gRPC.

Envoy Proxy (https://www.envoyproxy.io/) supports proxying gRPC connections and can be configured to log out request information.

Some other example proxies include:

- Nginx https://medium.com/nirman-tech-blog/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-with-grpc-820d35642bff
- https://github.com/mwitkow/grpc-proxy
- https://github.com/mercari/grpc-http-proxy

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking for android there is a app called [HttpCanry](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guoshi.httpcanary&hl=en). It can log request/ respond.